# Potential theory for LCA groups

Tags: reference-request, topological-groups, potential-theory

I was wondering if there is a potential theory for locally compact abelian groups.

$\textbf{Edit:}$ What are the suitable analogs for logarithmic or [Newtonian potentials](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtonian_potential) in the context of LCA groups ?